# Creating a text file from other text files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a text file like this

```
word_1 root_of_word_A
word_2 root_of_word_B
word_3 root_of_word_C
word_4 root_of_word_A
```

And other document like this

```
root_of_word_A root_of_word_1
root_of_word_B root_of_word_2
root_of_word_C root_of_word_3
```

I have to replace in the first document with the other words of the second document, like this

```
word_1 root_of_word_1
word_2 root_of_word_2
word_3 root_of_word_3
word_4 root_of_word_1
```

I thought that I could make something like this with awk. I tried this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {print $1}{c[$2]++;next};c[$1]>0{print $2}' file1 file2
```

The problem is that I do not know how to print the first column of the file1 and the second of the file2.

Mention that the first file and the second have different number of lines and that there is only an example to make it more clear the thing I want to do (the problem is not to convert A to 1, is the whole root_of_the_word).

Comment: do you mean if 2nd column from document should iterate when number of lines are not same on both files ?

Comment: Sorry, no. I trying to print in a new document the first whole file, but instead of root_of_word_A, change it for root_of_word_1. The thing is the 2 file is also very large. So I can not change it manually

Comment: Is the second file (the root definition file) small enough to load the whole thing into memory? If so, this is a simple task for awk. This task can process the first file line by line, so it doesn't matter how large it is.

Answer (score 2):

If words in `file2` are unique then you can reverse the order of the files, build an array from `file2` and apply it to `file1`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $1,a[$2]}' file2 file1
word_1 root_of_word_1
word_2 root_of_word_2
word_3 root_of_word_3
word_4 root_of_word_1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a relational join operation.  There's a standard Unix command for that: `join`. *I wish more people knew about this wonderful tool!*

The `join` command joins two files on a common field.  However, the two files need to be sorted on that field.

The common field is field 2 of the first file (`file1.txt`), and field 1 of the second file (`file2.txt`). Sort the files on these fields:

```
$ sort -k2,2 -o file1.txt file1.txt
$ sort -k1,1 -o file2.txt file2.txt
```

Then perform the join on these fields (read the manual for `join`), specifying that we only want to have field 1 from the first file and field 2 from the second file as outputs, and sort the result (if needed):

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,2.2 file1.txt file2.txt | sort
word_1 root_of_word_1
word_2 root_of_word_2
word_3 root_of_word_3
word_4 root_of_word_1
```